# Symmetric distribution optimization problem of distances between points in $[0,1]$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions, combinatorial-optimization

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a probability distribution with support $[0,1]$. Let $x, y, z$ the outcomes of three i.i.d. random variables $X, Y, Z$ with distribution $\mathcal{D}$, sorted in increasing order, i.e., $x\le y\le z$, . Let $a=y-x$ and $b=z-y$. We define

$$\Delta=1-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{b}{a+b}\cdot a+\frac{a}{a+b}\cdot b\right]=1-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{2ab}{a+b}\right]$$

and

$$\Delta'=1-\mathbb{E}\left[\min(a,b)\right]~.$$

---

**Question:** What is the minimum value of the ratio $\rho(\mathcal{D})=\frac{\Delta}{\Delta'}$ over all probability distributions $\mathcal{D}$?
(*When $\mathcal{D}$ is uniform in $[0,1]$, we have $\rho=\frac{20}{21}$. Is there a distribution $\mathcal{D}^*$ such that $\rho(\mathcal{D}^*)< \frac{20}{21}$?*)

---

---

***Note:*** *This problem can be viewed as the "symmetric version" of question* [Probability distribution optimization problem of distances between points in the interval $[0,1]$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/372341/115803) *and is related to the (discrete) combinatorial problem* [Combinatorial optimization on the sums of differences of real numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365472/115803)

Comment: Are you sure this is stated correctly? As stated $\Delta$ looks close to $2$ but $\Delta'$ close to $1$. Maybe you mean $\Delta = \mathbb{E}[\begin{cases} 1-|x-y| &\textrm{if $x,y<t<z$} \\ 1-|y-z| &\textrm{if $x<t<y,z$}\end{cases}| x,y<t < z \textrm{ or } x<t<y,z]$?

Comment: Also, can you show the derivation of $\rho=\frac{16}{17}$ for $\mathcal{D}$ uniform?

Comment: Yes, thank you @SamHopkins
When $\mathcal{D}$ is uniform we can exploit the symmetry of the problem by writing 

$$\rho=
\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x}^{t}\int_{t}^{1} 1-(y-x)~dz\,dy\,dx\,dt\,+\,
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{t}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} 1-(z-y)~dz\,dy\,dx\,dt
}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x}^{t}\int_{t}^{1} 1-\min\{y-x,z-y\}~dz\,dy\,dx\,dt\,+\,
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{t}^{1}\int_{y}^{1} 1-\min\{y-x,z-y\}~dz\,dy\,dx\,dt}
$$

Comment: Huh, numerical simulations are not agreeing with the value $16/17$, and something seems a little fishy in your integrals in that you've dropped the absolute value signs.

Comment: Thank you @SamHopkins For the sake of simplicity and for the purpose of this question (which is related to question https://mathoverflow.net/q/365472/115803), I could simplify the conditional constraint by replacing it with $x<y<t<z~~~\vee~~~x<t<y<z$. Do you agree in this case we obtain $\frac{16}{17}$ when $\mathcal{D}$ is uniform?

Comment: The problem with your previous evaluation was you were trying to treat $x$ and $y$ as symmetric in the case $x,y < t < z$, but they are not symmetric for the value $1-\min(|x-y|,|z-y|)$.

Comment: With the new formulation, my computer is telling me that if $\mathcal{D}$ is the (discrete) uniform distribution on $\{0, 1/3, 2/3, 1\}$, then we get $\Delta/\Delta'=9/10$.

Comment: Ah, but that's an artifact of you writing $x < y$, where I think you want $x \leq y$.

Comment: With $x\leq y < t < z$ and similar, I  am not easily managing to better with discrete distributions than with the uniform on $[0,1]$ distribution.

Comment: Thank you @SamHopkins ! I will think about it.

Comment: A reformulation: let $x'\leq y'\leq z'$ be the random variables $x,y,z$ sorted in increasing order. Let $A=y'-x'$ and $B=z'-y'$. Then $\Delta=1-E[\frac{2AB}{A+B}]$ and $\Delta'=1-E[\min\{A,B\}]$.

Comment: Thank you @RonP !

Comment: Thank you @aorq I obtain $20/21$ simply calculated the expression $$\frac{\int_0^1 \int_x^1 \int_y^1 1-2(y-x)(z-y)/(z-x)}{\int_0^1 \int_x^1 \int_y^1 1-\min(y-x,z-y)}~.$$ Hence, my first calculation for the case when $\mathcal{D}$ is uniform was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{D}$ has density of $16/13$ on $[0,13/32]\cup[19/32,1]$, with no support elsewhere, then $\Delta=0.840$, $\Delta'=0.887$, and the ratio is $0.947$. This is less than the $20/21 = 0.952$ from the uniform distribution.

This may not be close to minimal overall, but it's close to minimal for distributions supported uniformly on $[0,u]\cup[1-u,1]$.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Matt Do you think one can find a similar argument even when $\Delta$ and $\Delta'$ are defined as follows (note that, in this case, we indeed have $\rho=16/17$ if $\mathcal{D}$ is uniform in $[0,1]$)?  $$\Delta=\mathbb{E}[a(1-b)+b(1-a)]$$ and $$\Delta'=\mathbb{E}[(a+b)(1-\min(a,b))]~.$$

Comment: For that definition, the uniform density on $[0,1/3]\cup [2/3,1]$ gets $\Delta=29/60$, $\Delta'=83/160$, and a ratio of $0.932$. This is less than the $16/17=0.941$ for the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. However, I won't make further comments on variants of these problems.

Comment: Thank you @Matt